# Fetch the Email template and show name in dropdown in VF page

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have some email templates manage in one folder name " Lead Process", about 12 emails template there.

So I need one dropdown in my VF page which shows all the email templates from that folder. When user select the template from the dropdown the text or html will be display in the Richtext box place below the dropdown.

Well in other langauge like in dotnet we just fire the `onChange` event or `onSelect` event in dropdown and by id we get the html content and paste it in richtext box...all these thing happen in javascript there.

Is it feasible in salesforce.. If **YES** please give me some idea. How it possible?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're interested in the `<apex:actionSupport>` VF tag, which allows you to call an action method in the controller and refresh and component on the page when an action is performed on a form element. In this case you would want bind it to the `onchange` event of your `<apex:selectList>`.

I had recently put together something similar for another project, so I changed it a bit to generalize it for you. The page/controller below should allow you to view email templates in any folder...you should be able to modify it for your purposes without too much difficulty.

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="SomeController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="View Email Template" id="emailTemplateBlock">
            Select Email Template Folder:
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedEmailTemplateFolder}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!emailTemplateFolderOpts}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshEmailTemplateSection}" rerender="emailTemplateBlock" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <br/>
            Select Email Template: 
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedEmailTemplate}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!emailTemplateOpts}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshEmailTemplateSection}" rerender="emailTemplateBlock" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <br/>
            <apex:outputPanel id="emailTemplateContentPanel" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(chosenEmailTemplate))}">
                <p><b>{!chosenEmailTemplate.Name} - Subject:</b> {!chosenEmailTemplate.Subject}</p>
                <pre>{!chosenEmailTemplate.Body}</pre>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController {

    private List<EmailTemplate> allEmailTemplates;
    private List<Folder> allEmailTemplateFolders;
    public String selectedEmailTemplateFolder {public get; public set;}
    public String selectedEmailTemplate {public get; public set;}
    public EmailTemplate chosenEmailTemplate {public get; private set;}

    public SomeController() {
        allEmailTemplates = [select Id, Name, Subject, Body, FolderId from EmailTemplate order by Name asc];
        allEmailTemplateFolders = [select Id, Name from Folder where Type = 'Email' order by Name asc];
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplateFolderOpts() {
        List<SelectOption> opts = new List<SelectOption>();
        opts.add(new SelectOption('null', ' - Select - '));
        for ( Folder f : allEmailTemplateFolders )
            opts.add(new SelectOption(f.Id, f.Name));
        // add an option for templates in the Unfiled Public folder
        opts.add(new SelectOption(UserInfo.getOrganizationId(), 'Unfiled Public'));
        return opts;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getEmailTemplateOpts() {
        List<SelectOption> opts = new List<SelectOption>();
        if ( selectedEmailTemplateFolder != null ) {
            opts.add(new SelectOption('null', ' - Select - '));
            Id selectedId = (Id) selectedEmailTemplateFolder;
            for ( EmailTemplate et : allEmailTemplates ) {
                if ( et.FolderId == selectedId )
                    opts.add(new SelectOption(et.Id, et.Name));
            }
        }
        return opts;
    }

    public PageReference refreshEmailTemplateSection() {
        // this is a bit ugly, but a consequence of not being able to set a SelectOption's value to null
        if ( selectedEmailTemplateFolder == null || selectedEmailTemplateFolder == 'null' ) {
            selectedEmailTemplateFolder = null;
            selectedEmailTemplate = null;
        }
        if ( selectedEmailTemplate == null || selectedEmailTemplate == 'null' ) {
            selectedEmailTemplate = null;
            chosenEmailTemplate = null;
        } else {
            Id selectedId = (Id) selectedEmailTemplate;
            for ( EmailTemplate et : allEmailTemplates ) {
                if ( et.Id == selectedId ) {
                    chosenEmailTemplate = et;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```